# Deleting a a Value thats in a file in registery editor using python 2.7 code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to access something like this:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography

Now at end where Cryptography is there is a file inside like this:

https://gyazo.com/d037c094845eb4364333afdd00fdc7b4

PICTURE ^^

How can I delete the MachineGuid WITHOUT getting this error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied << Error to fix.
```

So how can i do this? i need help.

---

How can I also locate the MachineGuid? because if I do this:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid it won't work.

---

The code I am using:

```
import _winreg
Key_Name = r'Software\Microsoft\Cryptography'
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Key_Name, 0, 
_winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
_winreg.DeleteKey(key, '')

raw_input('...')
```